# NullPointerException in JDBCInputFormat.open when trying to read DataSet from MS SQL

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, apache-flink

For proessing with Apache Flink I am trying to create a DataSet from data given in a Microsoft SQL database. The test_table has two columns, "numbers" and "strings" which contain INTs and VARCHARs respectively.

```
// supply row type info
TypeInformation<?>[] fieldTypes = new TypeInformation<?>[] {
    BasicTypeInfo.INT_TYPE_INFO,
    BasicTypeInfo.CHAR_TYPE_INFO,
};

RowTypeInfo rowTypeInfo = new RowTypeInfo(fieldTypes);

// create and configure input format
JDBCInputFormat inputFormat = JDBCInputFormat.buildJDBCInputFormat()
    .setDrivername("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
    .setDBUrl(serverurl)
    .setUsername(username)
    .setPassword(password)
    .setQuery("SELECT numbers, strings FROM test_table") 
    .setRowTypeInfo(rowTypeInfo)
    .finish();

// create and configure type information for DataSet
TupleTypeInfo typeInformation = new TupleTypeInfo(Tuple2.class, BasicTypeInfo.INT_TYPE_INFO, BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO);

// Read data from a relational database using the JDBC input format
DataSet<Tuple2<Integer, String>> dbData = environment.createInput(inputFormat, typeInformation);

// write to sink
dbData.print();
```

On execution, the following error happens and no output is created.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:714)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(JobManager.scala:660)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(JobManager.scala:660)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:401)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat.open(JDBCInputFormat.java:231)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.invoke(DataSourceTask.java:147)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:559)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This leaves me with no real clue where and how to look for a solution. Curiously, this piece of code worked before I changed my Flink JDBC version from 0.10.2 to 1.1.3. The RowTypeInfo part was not necessary with the old version, meaning it probably checked the types itself?, but apart from adding that to the code, nothing changed.

Chances are, then, that it has to do with the RowTypeInfo. I tried changing them around a bit, e.g. using `BasicTypeInfo.CHAR_TYPE_INFO` instead of `BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO` (as the column is a VARCHAR column), but the error remained.

Ideally, I would like to fix the NullPointer problem and proceed with a DataSet containing the information from the database. Considering the lack of documentation/tutorials and (working) examples, I also arrive at a more general question: Is it a good idea at all to try and process SQL data in Flink or is it just not meant for this? As of now, I'm starting to think it might be easier, though tedious if nothing else, to create a routine that reads from a database and saves its contents to a CSV file before starting a Flink job on that.

Comment: You say you've updated the Flink JDBC version to 1.1.3, but what about the rest of Flink?  [This issue on the Flink JIRA tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-4061) suggests that if you have older versions of other parts of Flink then you may get an NPE such as this.

Comment: You are right. My pom.xml refers to the Flink version via a variable and I forgot to change it after testing the new version of Flink JDBC. D'oh. Thanks a bunch!